# Does Postgres lock all rows in a query atomically, even across different tables via JOIN?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions, locking

I am getting a deadlock error on my code. The issue is that this deadlock error is happening on the very first query of the transaction. This query joins two tables, `TableA` and `TableB` and should lock a single row in `TableA` with `id==table_a_id`, and all the rows on `TableB` that have a foreign key for `table_a_id`.

The query looks as follows (I am using SQLAlchemy, this output is from printing the equivalent query from it and will have its code below as well):

```
SELECT TableB.id AS TableB_id
FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.table_a_id 
WHERE TableB.id = %(id_1)s FOR UPDATE
```

The query looks as follows in SQLAlchemy syntax:

```
query = (
    database.query(TableB.id)
    .select_from(TableA)
    .filter_by(id=table_a_id)
    .join((TableB, TableA.id == TableB.table_a_id))
    .with_for_update()
)

return query.all()
```

My question is, will this query atomically lock all those rows from both tables? If so, why would I get a deadlock already exactly on this query, given it's the first query of the transaction?

Comment: It might be helpful for Postgresql specialists to see the actual SQL generated - `print(query)` should do it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Thanks, I've added it now. I assumed the SQLAlchemy code was enough as pseudocode but I guess it makes sense to not leave any implementation detail assumptions on the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query will lock the rows one after the other as they are selected. The exact order will depend on the execution plan. Perhaps you can add `FOR UPDATE OF table_name` to lock rows only in the table where you need them locked.

I have two more ideas:

- rewrite the query so that it locks the rows in a certain order:

  ```
  WITH b AS MATERIALIZED (
     SELECT id, table_a_id
     FROM tableb
     WHERE id = 42
     FOR NO KEY UPDATE
  )
  SELECT b.id
  FROM tablea
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b
                WHERE tablea.id = b.table_a_id)
  ORDER BY tablea.id
  FOR NO KEY UPDATE;
  ```

  Performance may not be as good, but if everybody selects like that, you won't get a deadlock.
- lock the tables:

  ```
  LOCK TABLE tablea, tableb IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  ```

  That lock will prevent concurrent row locks and data modifications, so you will be safe from a deadlock.

  Only do that as a last-ditch effort, and don't do it too often. If you frequently take high table locks like that, you keep autovacuum from running and endanger the health of your database.

Comment: I actually want both tables to lock the respective rows, but it's unfortunate (although it makes sense) that it locks the rows in execution order. Thanks